# Function from alpha to int

Tags: sml, smlnj

So i have a function that i'm trying to write:

```
fn (x:'a) => ???
(type: 'a -> int)
```

I've tried doing this:

```
fn (x:'a) => (x:int)
```

But obviously that returns a match constraint error. So is there any way I could go about doing this?

=== EDIT ===

Is there any way of 'reversing' the function? By this i mean having a function of type:

```
int -> 'a
```

Comment: Just return any integer of your choice.

Comment: @AaditMShah is there a way to reverse the function? Like go from int to 'a?

Comment: Yes, there is. Either go into an infinite loop or throw an error.

Comment: @AaditMShah how exactly would I do this without using exceptions?

Comment: The function `fun f (x : int) = f x` has the type `f : int -> 'a` and the function `fun g x = 0` has the type `g : 'a -> int`.

Comment: Is there a way to return a tuple of alphas? When i try `fun f (x:int) = (f x, f x);` it gives me a circularity error

Comment: Yes, first define `fun f (x : int) = f x` and then define `fun g (x : int) = (f x, f x)`. However, I don't understand why you want a tuple of undefined values. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Its for an assignment, I tried what you suggested before but it gives you the type `int -> 'a * 'b` and not `'a * 'a`

Comment: Try `fun g (x : int) = let val y = f x in (y, y)`.